# How to modify annotations on a masked image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a task that requires me to return the count of objects in the foreground of an image and I have the annotations that draw the bounding boxes for the objects in both the foreground and the background.

What I have done so far:

1. Extracted the foreground threshold using opencv Otsu Threshold functions.
2. Created an inverted mask from the extracted foreground such that when imposed on the image masks out (blacks out) the background.

Now, the label annotations that I have, I use them to draw the bounding boxes using the `cv2.rectangle` method.

What I need to do next is to draw these annotations (bounding boxes) only on the foreground objects. A naive way that I can think of is to validate if any (or all) of the 4 pixels for the corner of the rectangle is black and skip that bounding box but is there any existing method or better approach to this?

Comment: Please show your code and images. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).